# How to compute mean of two floating-point numbers?

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic, ieee-754

What is the most accurate way to compute mean of two numbers in floating-point arithmetic? Let's consider the most common double precision 64-bit numbers.

1. `(a + b) / 2`
2. `a / 2 + b / 2`
3. `a + (b - a) / 2`

These ways of computing the mean can give different results as can be seen in the C++ code below:

```cpp
double a = 1.2;
double b = 3.6;
double mean1 = (a + b) / 2.0;
double mean2 = a / 2.0 + b / 2.0;
double mean3 = a + (b - a) / 2.0;
cout << fixed << setprecision(20);
cout << "mean1: " << mean1 << endl;
cout << "mean2: " << mean2 << endl;
cout << "mean3: " << mean3 << endl;
```

which produces result

```
mean1: 2.39999999999999991118
mean2: 2.39999999999999991118
mean3: 2.40000000000000035527
```

Question [Mathematical properties of the computed average value of two floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690055/mathematical-properties-of-the-computed-average-value-of-two-floating-point-numb) compares cases 1 and 2. Brief conclusion is that accuracy is the same, but case 1 can overflow, while case 2 can underflow.

`mean1` and `mean2` seem to provide more accurate result, as they are closer than `mean3` to the true value 2.4. It seems that it is always the case that `mean3` is less precise. Intuitively it makes sense, because calculation of mean3 requires 3 operations, so there are more chances to lose precision, while calculation of mean1 requires only 2 operations.

---

**update:**
1.2 and 3.6 are stored as

```
1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
3.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
```

So their true mean is

```
2.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

However this value can not be represented in doulbles. The closest double value happens to be `mean1`, where `mean1` and `mean3` are

```
2.399999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375 (difference 1.11e-16)
2.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625   (difference 3.33e-16)
```

---

I've stumbled upon the third case in Fortran code [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~oleary/LBFGS/FORTRAN/linesearch.f](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Eoleary/LBFGS/FORTRAN/linesearch.f)

```fortran
stpf = stpc + (stpq - stpc)/2
```

```fortran
stp = stx + p5*(sty - stx)
```

where `p5` is 0.5

I'm not sure what the motivation was for this way of calculating mean. Probably it is the case of for n=2 of running average, as discussed in [numerically stable running average of floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951711/numerically-stable-running-average-of-floating-point-values) or in https://diego.assencio.com/?index=c34d06f4f4de2375658ed41f70177d59, but it improves accuracy only for large number of elements.

If this is an attempt to avoid overflow, it doesn't seem to work. All three cases can produce either overflow or underflow.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double mean1(double a, double b) {
    return (a + b) / 2.0;
}

double mean2(double a, double b) {
    return a / 2.0 + b / 2.0;
}

double mean3(double a, double b) {
    return a + (b - a) / 2.0;
}

void test(double a, double b) {
    cout << setprecision(20);
    cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << endl;
    cout << "mean1: " << mean1(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "mean2: " << mean2(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "mean3: " << mean3(a, b) << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    test(1e+308, 1e+308); // case 1 overflow
    test(4e-324, 4e-324); // case 2 underflow
    test(-1e+308, 1e+308); // case 3 overflow
}
```

```
a: 1.000000000000000011e+308, b: 1.000000000000000011e+308
mean1: inf
mean2: 1.000000000000000011e+308
mean3: 1.000000000000000011e+308

a: 4.9406564584124654418e-324, b: 4.9406564584124654418e-324
mean1: 4.9406564584124654418e-324
mean2: 0
mean3: 4.9406564584124654418e-324

a: -1.000000000000000011e+308, b: 1.000000000000000011e+308
mean1: 0
mean2: 0
mean3: inf
```

Furthermore, performance is a tiny bit worse for the third case (however results should be considered with caution, as they can greatly vary depending on context, but generally code with smaller number of instructions runs faster)

```cpp
static void case_1(benchmark::State& state) {
  volatile double a = 1.2;
  volatile double b = 3.6;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize((a + b) / 2.0);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(case_1);

static void case_2(benchmark::State& state) {
  volatile double a = 1.2;
  volatile double b = 3.6;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a / 2.0 + b / 2.0);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(case_2);

static void case_3(benchmark::State& state) {
  volatile double a = 1.2;
  volatile double b = 3.6;
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a + (b - a) / 2.0);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(case_3);
```

https://quick-bench.com/q/V_STrIZ5CmIL0Q3KpbLX6G9-G90

Probably there are some logic behind that choice that I'm missing. Probably the code above was meant to be run on a different hardware that didn't support IEEE 754? So, is there any reason to compute mean as `a + (b - a) / 2` instead of `(a + b) / 2`? Or is it just a slight inaccuracy and the straightforward way should be used to compute mean?

Comment: As you know floating point has limited precision, so already from the outset, 1.2 is not *exactly* that number when stored in floating point representation. If you have to worry about the differences you list at the top, then this is an indication you are using the wrong data type to start with.

Comment: There are no `double` values that are exactly equal to `1.2` or `3.6` or `2.4`. You are computing the mean of 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 and 3.600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625.

Comment: I've updated the question and clarified this case. `(a + b) / 2` computes result as accurately as possible for the result to be representable as double , but `a + (b - a) / 2` loses some precision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best midpoint formula for floating point numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617662/whats-the-best-midpoint-formula-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Related CppCon talk: [std::midpoint? How Hard Could it Be?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBtAGxBh-XI) -- floating point is handled starting around 48:40

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For accuracy, `(a + b) / 2` or `a / 2 + b / 2` should be preferred, because division by 2 is *lossless* in floating point unless it "underflows".  The `/ 2` just decrements the exponent, so, really, errors are only introduced in the addition.

You can `* 0.5` instead of `/ 2.0` if you like -- it makes no difference.

The form `a + (b - a) / 2`, however guarantees that:

- If both `a` and `b` are nonnegative finite values, then so is the result.  The `(a + b)/2` form does not provide this guarantee; and
- If both `a` and `b` are nonnegative finite values, and `b >= a`, then the result is always `>= a` and `<= b`.  Neither of the other two forms provides that guarantee.  This can be important, for example, if you're doing a binary search.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense if the values are guaranteed to be nonnegative

Comment: This answer explicitely restricts the application to finite values, but note that a flaw of `a + (b - a) / 2` is the case when a is infinity, it delivers a nan instead of inf (which is incorrect unless b is also -inf, which we restricted with the nonnegative assertion).

Comment: Unless you are referring to overflow, disagree with "if both a and b are nonnegative finite values, then so is the result. The `(a + b)/2` form does not provide this guarantee" --> Please provide a counter example when `a >= 0`, `a >= 0` does not lead to `(a + b)/2` being `>= 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Nonnegative finite a and b guarantee that `(a + b)/2` is nonnegative, but not that it is finite. So, statement "`(a + b)/2` is nonnegative finite value" can be false.

Answer (score 3):

- **Avoid overflow**: `a + b` and `b - a` both risk a result of *infinity*, totally losing all precession.
- Note that a floating-point encoding may or may not support [subnormals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number).  So math near these values is challenging to make portable.
- `a/2` only might lose precision when `|a| < DBL_MIN*2` ( at wee end of the normal range) and `a` has select values ("odd" ones).  For most values `a/2` incurs no rounding.  In cases where there is precision loss, the result remains finite, unlike overflow.  This usually is more tolerable.

---

Given these issues, `a / 2 + b / 2` is the better choice when either values' magnitude is not small (not near `DBL_MIN`).

---

> What is the most accurate way to compute mean of two numbers in floating-point arithmetic?

Without resorting to wider math, a way to avoid all overflow and most underflow issues is by bringing the calculation near 1.0.  This is at least useful as a reference function to compare other code.

```
double avg(double a, double b) {
  // Extract exponent.
  int expoa, expob;
  a = frexp(a, &expoa);  // |a| is now in the [0.5...1.0) range, or 0.
  b = frexp(b, &expob);

  // Scale the exponent.
  int expo = max(expoa, expob);
  a = ldexp(a, expoa - expo);
  b = ldexp(b, expob - expo);
  double avg = (a + b)/2;
  return ldexp(avg, expo);
}
```

I assert the only great loss of precision occurs when one is zero, the `other` is non-zero and the `other/2 --> 0.0`.

---

**Etc**

Some languages allow wider types for intermediate calculations rendering the choice moot.  Same answer for all 3.

`x * 0.5` and `x / 2.0` may differ from `x / 2` as the former may incur floating point type promotion.  (e.g. `float x` to a `double` operation.)
`x / 2` rarely does.

Comment: Scaling might work, except if ldexp implementation is buggish... Why would it be buggish? Well, it is buggish both on Microsoft and Apple MacOS libraries...
Remember https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150888/should-ldexp-round-correctly for example...

Comment: Ah, I found the Apple one, follow https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm/issues/383

Comment: @aka.nice That [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150888/should-ldexp-round-correctly) does not come up in this answer's `ldexp(a, expoa - expo); b = ldexp(b, expob - expo);` as the scaling never is more than the original.  Perhaps with `ldexp(avg, expo)` when `a, b` are near `DBL_MIIN` and differ in sign - do you have a sample `avg(a,b)` in mind?

Comment: yes when a and b are near DBL_MIN, on windows. take `a=ldexp(5.0,-1074);` and `b=ldexp(10.0,-1074);`; `(a+b)/2` should round to nearest even, that is to upper `ldexp(8.0,-1074)`. I guess the final `return ldexp(avg, expo);` will answer the wrong result with MSVC, at least up to 2017, did not try more recent ones.

Comment: `double a = ldexp(5.0, -1074);` 
`double b = ldexp(10.0, -1074);` 
`printf("(a+b)/2=%a avg(a,b)=%a \n", (a+b)/2, avg(a,b));` 
does indeed print two different results compiled with MSVC 2017 `(a+b)/2=0x0.0000000000008p-1022 avg(a,b)=0x0.0000000000007p-1022`.

Comment: @aka.Nice work.  (For reference, if we had more precision the "right" answer would have been `0x0.00000000000078p-1022`) At some level, both answers are right as the true math result is half way between those two representable `double`s.  C allows in such cases, the result is either one of them controlled by the rounding mode and implementation details.  With IEEE (assuming nearest, ties to even rounding mode), 0x0.0000000000008p-1022 is correct ( as I experience as "avg(a,b)=0x1p-1071").  So old MS C is not C "wrong", just not IEEE correct.